# Can C++17 be used together with CUDA using clang?

Tags: c++, cuda, clang, c++17

As far as using `nvcc`, one needs to use the corresponding `gcc` (currently max. 5.4 I believe) in conjunction. This of course somewhat prevents one from using C++17 on the host side.

Since C++17 can be compiled using `clang 5` and upwards (see [here](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html)), and one can compile cuda code as well (see [here](http://llvm.org/docs/CompileCudaWithLLVM.html)), **is it possible to use both C++17 and CUDA at the same time** (or can there be problems, e.g. with the CUDA runtime)?

Comment: There is a cppcast podcast episode about cuda and modern C++ that may get you started on the research to answer this.  Or I guess you could just try it and see what works; somethibg like this is going to.be continuously changing at this point in time.  By C++17 do you mean compiler support or library support, for example?

Comment: I would also very much hope you could take the time to experiment and answer this question yourself... +1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, as you already guessed the CUDA clang frontend is indeed ahead in C++ feature support, even in device code. It was already in the past, introducing C++14 features before NVCC which was mostly unnoticed by the community.

Take this C++17, unnecessarily modified `if constexpr`, snippet: [Fibo](https://hackernoon.com/a-tour-of-c-17-if-constexpr-3ea62f62ff65)

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cstdio>

constexpr unsigned
fibonacci(const unsigned x) {
    if constexpr (false)
    {
        return 0u;
    }
    if( x <= 1 )
        return 1;
    return fibonacci(x - 1) + fibonacci(x - 2);
}

__global__
void k()
{
    constexpr unsigned arg = fibonacci(5);
    printf("%u", arg);
}

int main()
{
    k<<<1,1>>>();
    return 0;
}
```

It already runs with `clang++ -std=c++17 -x cuda`: https://cuda.godbolt.org/z/GcIqeW

Nevertheless, for this specific example, C++17 extended lambdas and C++14 relaxed constexpr are that important in modern C++, that even in C++11 and C++14 mode of NVCC 8.0+ flags were added to enable those features already: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/new-compiler-features-cuda-8/

That means the above example compiles for example with NVCC 9.2 even without `__device__` qualifiers when removing the demonstrating C++17 `if constexpr` construct and adding `-std=c++14 --expt-relaxed-constexpr` flags.

Here is a list about C++ standard support on the device side for `nvcc` and `clang -x cuda`: https://gist.github.com/ax3l/9489132#device-side-c-standard-support (NVCC 11.0 supports device-side C++17 now.)

Comment: Still C++17 is not supported with Visual Studio (msvc). 2020-04-15 with even the latest releases of cuda 10.2 and Visual Studio 2019 msvc.

Comment: Would you be so kind to illustrate how to configure CMake to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5):

Currently up to C++14 is supported in device code (Introduced  in [CUDA 9](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cuda-9-features-revealed/))

```
--std {c++03|c++11|c++14}
```

[Options for Specifying Behavior of Compiler/Linker](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-altering-compiler-linker-behavior)

However, if your host is only using C++17, it should be possible to use separate compilation and link them with library. [Separate Compilation and Linking of CUDA C++ Device Code](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/separate-compilation-linking-cuda-device-code/)

Update: formatting and more info

Comment: C++17 in device code is supported in CUDA 11.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this same problem, and here's a simple example for anyone who meets the same problem too.

Assume that there're 3 files: `main.cpp` `cuda_calling.cpp` `cuda_calling.h`,
in which, the `main.cpp` uses `c++17` or what so ever that your `nvcc`does not support. As the name suggested, the `cuda_calling.cpp` must be compiled by `nvcc`.

First, build `cuda_calling.cpp` as a lib (as in the real case, there may be many files calling cuda. Otherwise, it's OK to build as an object file i.e `cuda_calling.o`). The output file is assumed as `lib_cudacalling.a`. Then build the `main.cpp` and the whole project as a cmake file:

```
cmake_minimun_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(separate)
add_compile_options(-std=c++17)
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}.o OBJECT main.cpp) # build as an object file first
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${PROJECT_NAME}.o>)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} cuda_calling) # you may need to specify the path
```

You can see that the key point is to build them *separately*.