# How to make CMake use clang for CUDA to support c++17

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda, clang, nvcc

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47959767/can-c17-be-used-together-with-cuda-using-clang), it is possible to use c++17 with cuda by using clang.  However, I couldn't find how to setup `CMakeLists.txt` to accomplish this.

I enable c++17 with

```
add_compile_options(-std=c++17)
```

Out of the box with the following

```
    enable_language(CUDA)
```

`nvcc` complains

```
nvcc fatal   : Value 'c++17' is not defined for option 'std'
```

Adding the following as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24413317/cmake-script-for-cuda-6-0-with-c11)

```
    set(CUDA_HOST_COMPILER clang++)
    set(CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER /usr/bin/clang++)
```

`clang` to complain

```
clang: error: language not recognized: 'cu'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
```

Comment: dam it... why doesn't `nvcc` complain when I do `add_compile_options(-std=c++14)` though?